# Why do types like atomic_bool or atomic_char exist?

Tags: c, thread-safety

Why do atomic types of such small integer exist, if they can be written in one instruction on every (normal) machine?

Comment: Atomics will create a memory barrier: force all caches to flash, and prevent the optimizer from re-ordering memory accesses to that variable around the barrier.

Comment: In my comment above _flash_ should be _flush_.

Comment: As you say, many _normal_ machines use just one instruction for some operations on the underlying types. But this cannot be expected for _all_ machines...